# nuspec file inside nupkg

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm having problems with a custom .nupkg file I have created as the .nuspec file is being added to the package itself.  The .nuspec file is held directly under the \src directory and I am using the following command to create the package:

```
nuget pack .\src\package.nuspec -Version 1.0.0.0 -OutputDirectory C:\Packages\
```

I am packing directly against the .nuspec file since my solution contains multiple projects each targeting a different .Net version.

Inside the package file, the two files at the root are the "[Content Types].xml" and the .nuspec file (besides the "_relS", "lib" and "package" directories).

For reference I have not yet posted the package and have just a local repository directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `nuspec` file outside the `src` folder

```
baseFolder
|- src 
   |- [contents]
   |- [contents]
|- package.nuspec
```

Now, run the command in `baseFolder`

```
nuget pack package.nuspec -Version 1.0.0.0 -OutputDirectory C:\Packages\
```